# Mongo aggregate lookup query on nested collection

Tags: python, mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, subquery

I have the following 2 collections:

### Uploads

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('63121ccf5b5ccfa64d64b50b'),
    school_id: '1',
    department: 'asas',
    files: [
        {
            fileName: '1',
            fileHash: 'c83b143bb0852863897698d66488db01c8ec308e',
            fileExtension: 'image',
            docClassifier: 'exam',
            encrypted: false,
        },
        {
            fileName: '2',
            fileHash: '6134d8550b20a4cb9125409975a31b939ab2e79d',
            fileExtension: 'pdf',
            docClassifier: 'assessment',
            encrypted: false,
        },
        {
            fileName: '3',
            fileHash: '65c3ee9af91a8034eb70cd26baf08778783a6671',
            fileExtension: 'pdf',
            docClassifier: 'assessment',
            encrypted: false,
        }
    ]
},
...
```

### Files

```
{
      _id: ObjectId('63123e6f69822fe2c230aa99'),
      fileName: '1',
      fileHash: 'c83b143bb0852863897698d66488db01c8ec308e',
      qna_status: 'pending',
},
{
      _id: ObjectId('63123e7f97b92edcfda9ac1b'),
      fileName: '2',
      fileHash: '6134d8550b20a4cb9125409975a31b939ab2e79d',
      qna_status: 'pending',
},
{
      _id: ObjectId('63123e8d83220fac63da336a'),
      fileName: '3',
      fileHash: '65c3ee9af91a8034eb70cd26baf08778783a6671',
      qna_status: 'completed',
},
...
```

I want the output as a join operation of both the collections which contains all **pending** documents whose **fileExtension** is **pdf**. The output must have **all** details from **files collection** and fileExtension, docClassifier from its corresponding nested object in uploads.

**Key here is fileHash**

Eg. output of the above example would be:

```
{
     _id: ObjectId('63123e7f97b92edcfda9ac1b'),
     fileName: '2',
     fileHash: '6134d8550b20a4cb9125409975a31b939ab2e79d',
     qna_status: 'pending',
     fileExtension: 'pdf',
     docClassifier: 'assessment',
},
...
```

---

My mongod version is 4.4 and i am using mongo client in python flask.

I tried the following

```
ans = list(files.aggregate([{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "uploads",
        "let": {
            "id": "$fileHash",
        },
        "pipeline": [
            {
            "$match": {
                "$expr": {
                "$eq": ["$$id", "files.fileHash"],
                },
                "files.fileExtension": "pdf",
            },
            },
        ],
        "as": "data",
        },
    }
]))
```

but it doesn't return any value from uploads collection. (data : [] is in the output)

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vfiHl40Cmd9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query i created to solve my issue:

```
db.files.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      fileHash: "$fileHash"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "uploads",
      localField: "fileHash",
      foreignField: "files.fileHash",
      as: "op",
      let: {
        fileHash: "$fileHash"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: "$files"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$files.fileHash",
                "$$fileHash"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      docClassifier: {
        $first: "$op.files.docClassifier"
      },
      fileExtension: {
        $first: "$op.files.fileExtension"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "qna_status": "pending",
      "fileExtension": {
        "$in": [
          "pdf",
          "doc"
        ]
      },
      "docClassifier": {
        "$nin": [
          "lab",
          "study_guides "
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bY0UGt4MXeM

Any other ideas and/or answers are still welcomed!